# Transfering an Incoming call to loudspeaker

Tags: applications

My Question is Can I transfer a call to loudspeaker or external speaker directly through app which the phone has when i get an incoming call

Thanks In Advance !!!

Comment: How is the speaker connected? Headphone jack, bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) should be able to do this. Create an Event "Phone Ringing" profile to perform the "Speakerphone" task (which you configure to turn the speakerphone on). This can be configured to only activate for certain callers if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Some Androids have a Car mode (often branded by manufacturer) in which you can say it will be auto-answered when ringing and the call will go over speaker.

If your device doesn't have a car mode or it doesn't work for you, you can try one of the many apps available which can handle this function for you: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=auto%20answer%20calls&c=apps (first app seems simple and serving your described needs, but I would always recommend to check out a few).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, my AT&T SGS3 with Android 4.3 has another way to do this: Under the `Settings` app, on the `My Device` tab, there is a section for `Voice Control`. If `Incoming Calls` is checked, then you can answer calls with the voice command "Answer" when the phone is ringing. Answering a call with the voice command will automaticallly turn on the speaker.